# Saving Surface to Bitmap and optimizing DirectX screen capture in C#

Tags: c#, image, optimization, save, slimdx

after a whole day of testing I came up with this code, which captures current screen using DirectX (SlimDX) and saves it into a file:

```
Device d;

public DxScreenCapture()
{
    PresentParameters present_params = new PresentParameters();
    present_params.Windowed = true;
    present_params.SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard;
    d = new Device(new Direct3D(), 0, DeviceType.Hardware, IntPtr.Zero, CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing, present_params);
}

public Surface CaptureScreen()
{
    Surface s = Surface.CreateOffscreenPlain(d, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, Format.A8R8G8B8, Pool.Scratch);
    d.GetFrontBufferData(0, s);
    return s;
}
```

Then I do the following:

```
   DxScreenCapture sc = new DxScreenCapture();
```

..code here

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        // Begin timing
        stopwatch.Start();

        Surface s = sc.CaptureScreen();
        Surface.ToFile(s, @"c:\temp\test.png", ImageFileFormat.Png);

        s.Dispose();

        stopwatch.Stop();

        textBox1.Text = ("Elapsed:" + stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
    }
```

**The results are:**

**0. when I don't save surface:** avg. elapsed time: 80-90ms

**1. when I also save Surface to BMP file:** format: ImageFileFormat.Bmp , avg. elapsed time: 120ms, file size: 7mb

**2. when I also save Surface to PNG file:** format: ImageFileFormat.Png , avg. elapsed time: 800ms, file size: 300kb

**The questions are:**

**1.** Is it possible to optimise current image capture? According to this article - Directx screen capture should be faster than GDI. For me, GDI usually takes 20ms to get a "Bitmap", whereas it takes 80ms to get "Surfare" using DX (both without saving).

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274461/Very-fast-screen-capture-using-DirectX-in-Csharp

**2a.** How to save Surface to PNG image format faster? When I save surface to 7mb BMP file it takes almost 6 times less time, than when I save the same surface to 300kb PNG file..

**2b.** Is it possible to save Surface directly to Bitmap so I don't have to create temporary files?

So I don't have to do following: **Surface -> image file; image file open -> bitmap;**, but instead: **Surface -> bitmap**

that's all for now. I'll gladly accept any tips, thanks!

**Edit:**

Just solved 2b by doing:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(SlimDX.Direct3D9.Surface.ToStream(s, SlimDX.Direct3D9.ImageFileFormat.Bmp));
```

**Edit2:**

```
Surface.ToFile(s, @"C:\temp\test.bmp", ImageFileFormat.Bmp);
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(@"C:\temp\test.bmp");
```

is faster than:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(SlimDX.Direct3D9.Surface.ToStream(s, SlimDX.Direct3D9.ImageFileFormat.Bmp));
```

by 100 ms!!! Yeah, I couldn't believe my eyes too ;) I don't like the idea of temporary file creation, but a 50% performance increase (100-200ms instead of 200-300+) is a very good thing.

Comment: I think png can compress faster than 800 ms. Try if it is faster if you first write to a memorystream.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use SlimDX library you can also try

```
public Bitmap GimmeBitmap(Surface s)
{
    GraphicsStream gs = SurfaceLoader.SaveToStream(ImageFileFormat.Bmp, s);
    return new Bitmap(gs);
}
```

and try the same for .png - I did not test performance but **it have to** be faster than using disc temporary file :)

and as for 1st question - try to only once create surface and then on every screenshot only put into it device's buffer data and create the bitmap

```
d.GetFrontBufferData(0, s);
return new Bitmap(SurfaceLoader.SaveToStream(ImageFileFormat.Bmp, s));
```

this should save you some time :)

Comment: SlimDX doesn't work that way.. I get tons of errors with "SurfaceLoader" (The name 'SurfaceLoader' does not exist in the current context). I think that I has something to do with "Managed DirectX" library, which is not supported in .net 4 so I can't add the reference. It's like C# VisualStudion doesn't know what "SurfaceLoader" and "GraphicsStream" are..

Comment: P.S. I've already installed DX SDK but unfortunattely there is no "Managed DX" reference in VS2010. After some digging I found out that we no longder(June 2010 SDK+) can use DX, all that's left is SlimDX (wrapper) or XNA (used mainly for game dev).

Comment: SurfaceLoader is not in SlimDX but in native DirectX (Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.SurfaceLoader) and it works on .NET4... And if you cannot find dll for managed code go look at "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\DirectX for Managed Code".

Answer (score 1):

If performance really is an issue, you should consider writing your code in `C++` instead. Therefor you dont need an external library but can directly access the **backend**-buffer of your video card via Windows-API + DirectX.

Accessing the backend(-video)-buffer is a lot faster than reading from the frontend-buffer.

To optimize performance (which also awnsers your **question 1**) use multithreading (see [TPL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) or [threading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=netcore-3.1) depending on your needs).

Here is an inside of how to do it in C++ [CodeProject examples in  C++](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5051/Various-methods-for-capturing-the-screen).
From my personal experience, DirectX was by far the fastest.

These steps

```
1. reading backend-buffer into a bitmap to process the data
2. spawning new thread to repeat step 1 while previous thread is still busy
```

take about `10-40ms` (together) - implemented in `C++` (on NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970M) and depending on the current workload of the hardware

### Possible middle course

If you want to stick with C# but also need the performance, writing a `C++`-dll for .NET (see [.NET Programming with C++/CLI (Visual C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/dotnet-programming-with-cpp-cli-visual-cpp?view=vs-2019)) which reads the video buffer and returns the data to your `C#`-Code will do the trick.